# Shipping Cost Estimator Code

Tags: javascript

Our website would like to implement an "estimated shipping cost" feature on our product skus. What is the best approach given that our back-end provider (Volusion) doesn't offer the feature? I'm posting a link to a product on Amazon that shows what we want (notice the "+ 54.99 shipping" in the pricing area):

[http://www.amazon.com/Count-Simpson-Strong-Tie-ABU88-Standoff/dp/B00K23390I/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1421081979&sr=8-8&keywords=abu88](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00K23390I)

The javascript they appear to be using is here:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  P.when("jQuery").execute(function($) {
    var form = $("#addToCart"),
      thirdParty = $("#soldByThirdParty"),
      args = {
        a: form.find("[name=ASIN]").val(),
        me: form.find("[name=merchantID]")
          .val()
      };

    $('#selectQuantity [name="quantity"]').change(
      function() {
        args.qt = this.value;
        $.get("/gp/product/du/quantity-sip-update.html",
          args,
          function(data) {
            data = $(data);
            thirdParty.find(".price3P").html(data.filter(".price").text());
            thirdParty.find(".shipping3P").html(data.filter(".plusShippingText").text());


          }
        );
      }
    );
  }); < /script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really know much about javascript. I can at least tell we will have to edit the above code to fit our website since we don't have any "third party" sellers (it comes directly from us). Here is an example of one of our product skus: http://www.mudsupply.com/Vulkem-45-SSL-Gray-29-oz-Polyurethane-Sealant-p/4552.htm

Comment: Ask your shipping provider (USPS, UPS, FedEx, etc) for a link to their cost calculator API.  Such as https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/welcome.htm